# how to call a postgres function with geometry as parameter?

Tags: postgresql

I have a function which accepts geometry as parameter

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION rings(geometry, DOUBLE PRECISION)
  RETURNS geometry AS
$BODY$
...
```

and the way I am calling is

```
select rings(POLYGON((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0)), 6000)
```

or with quotes and other ways but doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question to ask is how to **create** a geometry.  I am assuming you are using PostGIS.

The quick and dirty solution is to use the automatic conversion from text to geometry. Note that the input is between singe quotes.

`'POLYGON((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0))'::geometry`

A cleaner way would be to use the function to build a geometry from text

`ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0))')`